# Метод Parse (double.Parse, int.Parse) в вэб-службе asmx выдает исключение ArgumentNullException при получении параметров запроса

Tags: c#, asp.net

Имеется javascript-код, фрагмент метода класса:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("lat", this.LatLng.lat);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/MyDbService.asmx/MyDbMethod", true);
xhr.send(formData);
```

Фрагмент метода `MyDbMethod` вэб-службы:

```
string request_lat = Context.Request.Params["lat"];
bd.WriteToLog("request_lat = " + request_lat);
double lat = double.Parse(request_lat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
bd.WriteToLog("lat = " + lat);
```

Полученные данные на стороне вэб-службы проверяю, записывая лог в текстовый файл, в джаваскрипте вывожу в консоль.

Параметр `lat` успешно передается на сервер, считывается сначала в переменную `request_lat`, затем уже в статусе `lat` также успешно записывается в лог. Однако ответ от сервера приходит такой:

> ```
> `System.ArgumentNullException:` Значение не может быть неопределенным. Имя параметра: `value`
> в `System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)`
> в `System.Double.Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider)`
> в `MyDbService.MyDbMethod() в <...>MyDbService.asmx.cs:`строка 107
> ```
>
> Строка 107 содержит вызов метода `double.Parse`.

В чем может быть проблема?

**Обновление**

О наличии исключения я узнаю в консоли браузера. Метод вэб-службы продолжает работать после строки 107, запись в базу данных проходит успешно (сейчас тестирую без записи), данные, записанные через `Context.Response.Write`, успешно передаются браузеру. Браузер же пишет в консоли "некорректно" и при нажатии на ссылку открывает в новом окне сообщение об исключении.

Comment: Так что же записывается в лог в строке 106? При записи в лог лучше окружать значение скобками или кавычками, чтобы были видны пробелы в начале и в конце.

Comment: Забыла указать, вот строчки из лога: request_lat = 59.936526419625935
lat = 59,9365264196259

Comment: Очень странно что сработал второй WriteToLog() -- в строке 108 -- у вас же произошло исключение в строке 107. Подозреваю что иногда от javascript на сервер приходит значение, а иногда нет.

Comment: Дополнила главное сообщение, срабатывает не только второй метод  WriteToLog(), но и все, что ниже. Такие подозрения у меня тоже были, но в лог же пишется все, что пришло. Также проходила по всем параметрам в цикле foreach, записывалось в лог все то же самое, что и отправлялось из джаваскрипта.

Comment: Смущает ещё способ получения параметра веб-метода: `Context.Request.Params["lat"]` -- почему не объявить его параметром метода явно?

Comment: В другие методы передаю параметры явно, а в этом методе в FormData записывается помимо прочего изображение.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте логировать подробнее и проверять правильность пришедшего значения (это в любом случае полезно):

```
string request_lat = Context.Request.Params["lat"];
bd.WriteToLog("request_lat = " + request_lat);
double lat;
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request_lat)
    bd.WriteToLog("lat is null or empty");
else if (!double.TryParse(request_lat, out lat))
    bd.WriteToLog("failed to parse lat value");
else
    bd.WriteToLog("lat = " + lat);
```

Comment: последовала вашему совету, добавив еще <code>string request_lat_2 = request_lat.Replace('.', ',');</code>  и <code>!double.TryParse(request_lat_2, out lat)</code>. Результат такой же, положительный. Кстати, проверила в Опере - никаких сообщений об исключении. Все описанное ранее относилось к Firefox. Дело в том, что при переносе сайта на хостинг данная функция вэб-службы перестала работать, потом обнаружилось это скрытое исключение, хотя, возможно, оно и не является причиной неработоспособности сайта на хостинге.